# When does separating digital and analog ground make sense, is it essential, and when is it not? Should I separate the grounds in this project?

Tags: analog, ground

I created a simple sequencer design based on several digital chips. The circuit is powered by a simple 7805 voltage regulator. When designing the board, I separated the analog ground of the power circuit from the rest. Is it right and make sense?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the only analog part is the regulator, then there is no point in separate grounds. There *are* some occasions when it is suitable but for modern parts that is very much a corner case.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: the tlc0820 is an ADC, one of the worst mixed signal part to handle. Switching regulators often need a good reference for the feedback loop, but the small linear one have everything inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different views on the problem. Holy wars were fought on the issue.
It's somewhat right and somewhat wrong. It is right to keep the return paths separated but how do you handle the transition points, i.e. ADCs DACs and mixed signal component in general?

The current view for complex boards is to keep one single ground plane (or ground mesh) and partition geographically the board in analog/digital/power/RF section to keep in check the return currents.

That said, your circuit doesn't seem to need a very performant ground system so it doesn't really matter. Just be sure to pick a point where join the two ground networks (that's essential, there must be a DC path between the grounds)

Comment: Yes, the two grounds network are connected on the board. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you ask about splitting grounds, voltage noise develops across a ground trace or plane when a time-varying current flows into it: U=Z*I, voltage noise is impedance times current. Unless you're doing high accuracy DC, the most problematic part of the impedance is the inductance, and that causes noise proportional to the derivative of current: di/dt. So the worst offenders are fast logic chips that do a lot of switching with fast edges (cpus, microcontrollers, 74AC/74LVC and the like, etc) and stuff like switching converters (high current switched fast = high di/dt).

GND is both a power supply, a current return for signals, and a voltage reference. So, "clean ground" consists mostly of keeping the voltage noise generated by the first two (power supply current and high di/dt currents) out of the "voltage reference" part. Mostly this is about placement, ie don't put the switching converter and the CPU next to the sensitive analog parts. If you split the grounds, sometimes it can work, but very often it prevents currents from returning through the shortest (lowest impedance) path, so they will find other ways to return where they must and instead of having less noise, you will have the same amount of noise (or more) elsewhere.

The circuit is mostly made of CMOS 4000 chips which are pretty slow and low current, clock frequency is low, so that makes the job a lot easier. Chips of these generations have worked fine on boards that look just like yours for decades. They don't make much noise, and being logic chips they have a high tolerance for noise too.

However, it looks like the ground pour on the left with the 7805 is not connected to the other ground pour covering the rest of the board. If this is the case, it won't work: power supply current has to return somewhere.

I should mention a few "clean ground" features that would apply to your board:

A voltage regulator's output is referenced to its GND pin, so putting the voltage regulator on a separate ground will create a stable power supply relative to that ground, but not to the other grounds. Likewise the regulator's output cap ground pin should be on the ground of the chips it supplies. So you should use just one ground pour for the entire board.

Also you already did the right thing by putting the ADC in a corner where no return current flows. The worst case would be between the power supply and the other chips, where all the noisy current flows in the ground.

The ADC "REF-" pin should probably be connected to GND for it to work, check the datasheet.

Now if you intend to use the ADC as an encoder you'll probably want the last LSB to be stable, so there should be less than 5V/256=20mV noise on both the input and the reference. I'm not sure you'll get that. Also I'm not sure you can turn a pot with a 1/256th angle accuracy.

Anyway, you can connect the pot's VCC and ground to the ADC REF+ and REF- pins, so they are both referenced to the same voltages used by the ADC. I mean, connect them with dedicated traces, not through the shared GND/VCC. You could also use a separate regulator just for VREF. You could also use a RC filter between VCC and VREF, but since the VREF pin internal resistance is quite low and your pot is 1k, the resistor would have to be pretty low like 100 ohms to not drop too much voltage. With a larger value cap like 470µF it should work fine.

Comment: The ground pout on left is connected with a small wire. Thanks a lot for your explanation.